# Securing authentication modals

Tags: ajax, security, ssl, authentication

Currently I am forced to serve my page under HTTP as I am unable to ssl the images so I get a bunch of mixed content warnings. One thing that has been implemented on my website is a bootstrap modal with my login form.

The form itself is sent through HTTPS. I also get console errors like so:

```
Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.[Learn More]
```

So primarily what I am trying to figure out is:

1. What risks am I facing by serving my login like this?
2. Is there anything I can do to make this approach more secure
   considering I cannot full ssl the site?

Comment: In what way are you unable to serve the images over HTTPS?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Right now im pulling images from taobao.com via their api but unfortunatly their cdn has broken ssl certs

Comment: I'd recommend proxying them through your server. That way you can use HTTPS from browser to your server